# Allow input type number only a number/float between 0-1

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to have an `input` number that allows any float between 0-1 including both whole numbers. But it's proving quite tricky just getting the backspace to actually delete a numbers as it comes as `NaN`

I got this:

```
const [rate, setRate] = useState<number>(0)

const addRate = (num: number) => {
  if (typeof num !== 'number') {
    setRate(0)
  } else {
    setRate(num)
  }
}

...
<input
  type='number'
  value={rate}
  onChange={e => addRate(parseFloat(e.target.value)}
/>
```

Comment: so add validation.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use achieve your goal with adding some conditions to the `addRate` state, also using `step` prop of `input` element:

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [rate, setRate] = useState(0);

  const addRate = (num) => {
    if (typeof num !== "number" || isNaN(num) || num > 1) {
      setRate(0);
    } else {
      setRate(num);
    }
  };
  return (
    <input
      type="number"
       value={rate === 0 ? "" : rate}
      step={0.01}
      onChange={(e) => addRate(parseFloat(e.target.value))}
    />
  );
}
```

[image: Edit vigorous-framework-x233g]

Comment: It does not work if you type 1 and then delete it you get `NaN`

Comment: What do you want exactly? Would you like to validate the input?

Comment: I want it to take only numbers between 0-1 including decimals, but just removing a number is already a problem

Comment: @Álvaro Updated answer. Check it again

Comment: It does not delete the initial 0 so if you type 1 you end up with 01

Comment: @Álvaro Check my answer again!

Comment: It still allows for `2` the max is not working, I fixed it with this on the else condition `setRate(num <= 1 ? num : rate)`

Comment: @Álvaro Please check the updated answer! :)

Comment: Yeah that works too! But the max on html is not doing anything then?

Comment: sorry there is a problem, it now accepts letters for some reason

Comment: Yes it should not allow any letters

Answer (score 0):

You can use on your input:

```
    <input type='number' value={rate}  min={0} max={1} step={0.000001} 
  onChange={e => addRate(parseFloat(e.target.value)} >
```

set the step the way you want to.
And for the NaN, try it:

```
if(typeof num == 'number' || isNaN(num))
```

let me know if it works!

Comment: will this still work if the precision is lower than 0.000001?

Comment: Yes, it will, but the input step will be 0.000001. You can set it to more or less precise by changing the step value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to work with inputs and numbers, to save you from a lot of headache (especially when using mobile devices to prompt user for a proper input type), fix errors caused by `.` vs `,`, save time on developing code and getting cleaner code thanks to using directives I suggest you to check out some alternatives. It's not mine but man do I use this alot. https://digit-only.firebaseapp.com/demo I highly suggest this. Floting numbers and inputs are a pain in the...

If you don't want "yet another package" then you can ofcourse just inspect the code the get some ideas: https://github.com/changhuixu/ngx-digit-only/blob/main/projects/uiowa/digit-only/src/lib/digit-only.directive.ts